# Hardware acceleration honoured by Vlc player but ignored by vlcj

Tags: java, javafx, vlc, libvlc, vlcj

I'm writing some code to play media, I noticed that vlc mediaplayer correctly honours the `--avcodec-hw` parameter, but vlcj, with the same parameter passed to the library

This is how I build the mediaplayer component

```java
//This uses jfx17

MediaPlayerFactory factory;
EmbeddedMediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

var args = new ArrayList<String>();
args.add("-vv");
args.add("--network-caching=100");
args.add("--avcodec-hw=vdpau_avcodec");

factory = new MediaPlayerFactory(args);
mediaPlayer = factory.mediaPlayers().newEmbeddedMediaPlayer();

var vs = new ImageViewVideoSurface(this.videoImageView);
mediaPlayer.videoSurface().set(vs);
videoImageView.setPreserveRatio(true);

String murl = "/tmp/mytestvideo.mp4";


mediaPlayer.media().play(murl);
mediaPlayer.controls().start();
```

In vlc I set the vdpau trough the GUI menu (tools->preferences->Input/codecs)

the command `nvidia-smi dmon` shows few percentage when using vlc (and `top` gives really low cpu usage) but 0 when using the javaFx applcation (and `top` gives a 30% cpu usage).

How can I force the GPU video decoding?

**EDIT:**
Here are the versions of the software I'm using:
Ubuntu 20.04
vlc media player: 3.0.9.2
vlcj: 4.7.3
vlcj-natives: 4.7.0
vlcj-javafx: 1.1.0

** EDIT **
edited according to @caprica no effect

Also, at runtime I force the parameter `-Dprism.forceGPU=true`

Comment: You should add versions of vclj and vlc.

Comment: Not sure if this will work or not, hence a comment not an answer, but try your avcodec-hw setting on the MediaPlayerFactory rather than the play() method.

Comment: @caprica tested as you suggested, on windows it seems to work (CPU usage goes up) but I don't know if it's windows itself or libvlc. On linux still no effect